# Problem loading a DLL with boost DLL from a different path when it has dependencies

Tags: c++, boost, dll, dllimport

I use `boost::dll` for loading libraries at runtime.

With the following code, I'm able to load a DLL even when it's in a different folder than the one with the executable:

```
auto creator = boost::dll::import_alias<pluginapi_create_t>(fileName, "createPlugin", boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations);
```

But I've got a problem when a DLL has other dependencies. This is an example of my folder structure:

```
Main Folder
|
|-program.exe
|
|-pluginsfolder
  |
  |-plugin1.dll
  |-plugin2.dll
  |-dependency.dll
```

If I load `plugin1.dll` (which has no other dependencies), it works.

If I load `plugin2.dll`, that requires `dependency.dll`, it doesn't work.

I suppose I could put all the DLLs in the same folder, and everything will begin to work again. But I'd like to keep plugins in separate folders because I want other users to be able to load plugins from their respective folders.

How can I load plugins with dependencies regardless their position in the filesystem?

Comment: See `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS` and `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` and follow links in the descriptions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa   How this translates to Boost I have no idea.

Comment: They can be used with `boost::dll`? I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I have no idea, the options exist at the OS level. DLL and cross-platform seems strange.

Comment: It's not strange. It's about loading libraries at runtime, so it's the same problem in Linux with .so files, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, thanks to Richard comments.

This is the command:

```
auto creator = boost::dll::import_alias<pluginapi_create_t>(fileName, "createPlugin", boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations | boost::dll::load_mode::load_with_altered_search_path);
```

I've added the `boost::dll::load_mode::load_with_altered_search_path` flag when loading, while searching how to use the corresponding `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` using by windows natively.